# python scikit-learn: how to modify the data of LeafNode after search the tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have get a tree by scikit-learn(python), and I search the tree by some data to get the relevant leafnode.
Then I want to modify the data that stored in the leafnode. How can I achieve this, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to so. please read the [ask] page as well as the [mcve] about providing examples.

Comment: Are you using DecisionTreeClassifier class? Which parameters do you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

@JoSSte's comment is right - providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example would really be helpful here. In the meantime, I would **highly** recommend reading this scikit-learn documentation and going through this example:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-download-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py

It takes you through parsing a DecisionTreeClassifier object's tree (and, I would assume, applies to individual trees in ensemble models like RandomForestClassifiers).

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I managed to find a roundabout solution strategy, thanks